# add class to li onclick

Tags: javascript, html

how will i go on to added a class to li class='active' on click and also on page load have the first li ( overview ) active by default ?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('overview');">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('reviews');">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('news');">News</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('gallery');">Gallery</a></li>
</lu>

<div id='overview' style='display: none;'>
<!-- overview content -->
</div>   

<div id='articles' style='display: none;'>
<!-- arcticles content -->
</div>   

<div id='news' style='display: none;'>
<!-- news content -->
</div>   

<div id='gallery' style='display: none;'>
<!-- gallery content -->
</div>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid, LI elements must be children of a UL or OL element.

Comment: Write a small *addClass* function (4 or 5 lines of code), then onload do something like `addClass(document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0], 'active');`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using jQuery if you have not already.  It really makes these a bit easier.

Strictly speaking, here is one way: (untested)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('overview', this);">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('reviews', this);">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('news', this);">News</a></li>    
<li><a href="#" onclick="showdiv('gallery', this);">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='overview' style='display: none;'>
<!-- overview content -->
</div>   

<div id='articles' style='display: none;'>
<!-- arcticles content -->
</div>   

<div id='news' style='display: none;'>
<!-- news content -->
</div>   

<div id='gallery' style='display: none;'>
<!-- gallery content -->
</div>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(id, a){
    if (window.activeA != undefined) {
        window.activeA.className = '';  // delcare window.activeA, if not already exists
    }

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    a.className = 'active';
    window.activeA = a;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The listener is passing a reference to the A element, not the LI.

Comment: You are right.  I will update.  It still would have worked, just a bad name of activeLi

Answer (score 0):

Here is a <kbd>[Quick JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/SujEb/)</kbd> that demonstrates swapping classNames and display of divs in pure JavaScript.

```js
var toggleDiv = function(self, id) {
    var li = self.parentNode,
        contents = document.getElementsByClassName('content'),
        menu = document.getElementById('menu'),
        children = menu.children,
        child = undefined,
        i = 0;

    // Loop over all content divs and show the active and hide all others.
    for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++)
        contents[i].style.display = contents[i].id == id ? 'block' : 'none';

    // Loop over all menu items and add active class to the selected
    // and remove from others if applicable.
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        child = children[i];

        if (child === li) {
            child.className = (child.className + ' active').trim();
        } else {
            if (child.className.indexOf('active') > -1) {
                child.className = child.className.replace('active', '').trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" onClick="toggleDiv(this, 'overview');">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="toggleDiv(this, 'reviews');">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="toggleDiv(this, 'news');">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="toggleDiv(this, 'gallery');">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="overview" class="content">Overview...</div>
<div id="reviews" class="content">Reviews...</div>
<div id="news" class="content">News...</div>
<div id="gallery" class="content">Gallery...</div>
```

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    background: #4679BD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
li>a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.content {
    display: none;
}
.active {
    background: #064CA8;
}
```

Comment: Regarding `Array.prototype.slice.call`, please don't use native methods on host objects. They are not guaranteed to work and will fail in some browsers in use.

Comment: I fixed this by using a vanilla for-loop.